# How to get the index of spaces of a string and relate that index of spaces to a new string in javascript?

Tags: arrays, string, indexing

**In JavaScipt**
I need to get the index of spaces of a string and relate that index of spaces to a new string.

```
Example: 
The string: "I am okay" 
The result: "Y es Iam"
Example 2:
The string: "how are you"
The result: "Iam goo d"
```

As you can see the index of the spaces has been preserved and related to the resulting string. I do not need anything case-sensative preserved.

I can not include code from what I've tried, as I have no idea how to go about this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```js
var srcStrX="How are you";
var applyToStrX="I am good";

function reSpace(srcStr, applyToStr) {
  var resultStr="";
  var srcStrCopy=srcStr.split("");
  var applyToStrSpaceless=applyToStr.split(" ").join("").split("");
  while(srcStrCopy.length && applyToStrSpaceless.length) {
    var character=srcStrCopy.shift();
    if(character==" ") resultStr+=character;
    else resultStr+=applyToStrSpaceless.shift();
  };
  return resultStr;
}

console.log(reSpace(srcStrX, applyToStrX));
console.log(reSpace("When you wish upon a star", "Doesn't matter who you are"));
```

Comment: Hey so ive used the code to implement for my needs. The code youve written, works for most cases. Except for the case that there is a space in the beggining. So something like " how are you" becomes "uoy era woh" without the space at the end of the result. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Sorry it becomes " uoy era woh" im assuming there should be a space at the end, no?

Comment: I don't know how you got the results you say you got.
The function has no reverse in it.
It is good as is.
Please provide both strings that allegedly caused the results you claim.
Thank you.